# locate blocks in the nginx.conf file

Tags: nginx

I need your help, i am new using nginx and i dont know what i am doing wrong, i am making my locate blocks to serve a .js but for some reason that i cant understang it does not go in my locate block, here is the nginx.conf file:

```
worker_processes  1;
pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    geoip_country         /usr/local/src/GeoIpbd/GeoIP.dat;
    geoip_city            /usr/local/src/GeoIpbd/GeoLiteCity.dat;
    access_log            logs/access.log;

    map $geoip_country_code $allowed {
        default             0;
        "VE"                1;
    }

    map $domain $value {
        default             "";
        dominio            "XXXXXX";
    }

    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        root /usr/local/nginx/html;
        listen       80;
        server_name  yyyyyyyy;

        location ~* '/vs/(?P<domain>.+)/' {
            if ($allowed){
                rewrite ^ /js/vs.js last;
            }
        }

        location = /js/vs.js {
            root html/js;
            expires 0;
            sub_filter_types  application/javascript;
            sub_filter_once   off;
            sub_filter        string $value;
        }
    }
}
```

My request is a script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yyyyyyyy/dominio/"></script>
```

This is the access.log file:

> GET /dominio/ HTTP/1.1" 404 570 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36

And my error.log file:

> /usr/local/nginx/html/dominio/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 190.199.171.220, server: localhost, request: "GET /marydice/ HTTP/1.1", host: "yyyyyyyy"

I do see in the error.log that is looking for a /usr/local/nginx/html/dominio/index.html route in my server which i dont have, somehow it see the request as if it were equal to a server path, and i dont have any idea why.

If someone can help me i would apreciate it

Comment: The default behaviour is `index index.html` (see [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index)).

Comment: thank you Richard, i did look that page, the problem did solve, the only thing i did was to put the "sendfile" to off and test it again and again and so on but nothing change, eventually i got tired and i go away, but when i get back and test it again, it works, i see the error and access log and i did not see the any error.
I dont know why the problem got solved, because i dont thing that just changing the sendfile to off and just wait the problem was going to solve, but well... 
Again, thank you for your hel